# Allow a variable to have multiple types in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have defined two types like -

```
type A = $ReadOnly<{
  a: ?$ReadOnlyArray<string>,
  b: ?string,
}>;
```

and

```
type B = $ReadOnly<{
  c: ?$ReadOnlyArray<boolean>,
  d: ?number,
}>;
```

I want to define a functional component which takes either of these two types e.g

```
type Input = {
  eitherType: type can be A or B
};

function abcd({eitherType}: Input): React.Node {
    // blah blah blah  
    // typecast to the particular type here
}
```

I don't want to use `any` to define the type, is there any other way to let this variable have either of the types?

Comment: So this is Typescript?

Comment: ```eitherType: A | B```. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) to create a type that can be one of two types:

```js
type Input = {
  eitherType: A | B
};
```

Comment: This makes casting to a particular type difficult.

Comment: Yes, the types in your example are difficult for a machine to pick apart. Typically Object types that need to be union'd have a common value, like a string `type`, that can be compared to [discriminate the union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).

Comment: or calling `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` to check for the existence of `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` would be sufficient to discriminate the types because each of those keys exists in exactly one type in the union.

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions is to implement Polymorphism here

```
Create Class A
Create Class B and inherit from Class A

then use Class Type as input type.

While calling the function declare Class A object and assign instance of B

Hope it would work
```